# Java: breaking out of while loop when encountering last line of scanner

Tags: java

I have the following code:

```
int ctr4 = 0;
int start3 = 0;

for(int system = 0; system < countsystems(args[0]); system++) {
    Scanner input2 = new Scanner(new File("internal2"));

    for(int r = 0; r < start3; r++){
        input2.nextLine();
    }

    Scanner input9t = new Scanner("");
    String scanstringadd = "";
    while (input9.hasNextLine()) {

        String scanstring = input9.nextLine();
        if(scanstring.isEmpty()) {
            break;
        }
        String scanstringprev = scanstring;
        scanstringadd += scanstring;
        System.out.println("scanstringadd:" + scanstringadd);
        input9t = new Scanner(scanstringadd);
    }

    start3 += (narray[ctr4] + 1);
    ctr4++;
}
```

How do I check for the last line of input9? If the last line is recognized, the while loop must break.

Edit: the purpose of recalling the while loop is that I have an inputfile like this:

```
(<E>,<A#>,A#),(A#,B#,C#),(B#,B#,C#),(Bb,Bb,Cb)|(Ab,Ab,Ab),(Bb,Bb,Cb),(Bb,Bb,Cb),(Bb,Bb,Cb)|
(   ,    ,  ),(  ,  ,  ),(  ,  ,  ),(  ,  ,  )|(  ,  ,  ),(  ,  ,  ),(  ,  ,  ),(  ,  ,  )|
(   ,    ,  ),(  ,  ,  ),(  ,  ,  ),(  ,  ,  )|(  ,  ,  ),(  ,  ,  ),(  ,  ,  ),(  ,  ,  )|
( A#,<A#>,  ),(  ,B#,  ),(B#,B#,C#),(Bb,Bb,Cb)|(Ab,Ab,Ab),(Bb,Bb,Cb),(Bb,Bb,Cb),(Bb,Bb,Cb)|
(   ,    ,  ),(  ,  ,  ),(  ,  ,  ),(  ,  ,  )|(  ,  ,  ),(  ,  ,  ),(  ,  ,  ),(  ,  ,  )|
( Ab,<Ab>,  ),(  ,Bb,  ),(Bb,Bb,Cb),(Bb,Bb,Cb)|(Ab,Ab,Ab),(Bb,Bb,Cb),(Bb,Bb,Cb),(Bb,Bb,Cb)|

(<D>,<A#>,A#),(A#,B#,C#),(B#,B#,C#),(Bb,Bb,Cb)|(Ab,Ab,Ab),(Bb,Bb,Cb),(Bb,Bb,Cb),(Bb,Bb,Cb)|
(   ,    ,  ),(  ,  ,  ),(  ,  ,  ),(  ,  ,  )|(  ,  ,  ),(  ,  ,  ),(  ,  ,  ),(  ,  ,  )|
(   ,    ,  ),(  ,  ,  ),(  ,  ,  ),(  ,  ,  )|(  ,  ,  ),(  ,  ,  ),(  ,  ,  ),(  ,  ,  )|
( A#,<A#>,  ),(  ,B#,  ),(B#,B#,C#),(Bb,Bb,Cb)|(Ab,Ab,Ab),(Bb,Bb,Cb),(Bb,Bb,Cb),(Bb,Bb,Cb)|
```

So the second 'system' has to be read in after the first has been read in.

Comment: It seem to me that `while (input9.hasNextLine())` will end the while loop just as intended.

Comment: change to a do while loop?

Comment: I also thought that, but a NoSuchElementException is thrown when I call input9t later in the program.

Comment: Why would a do-while loop work?

Comment: Because that's what a do-while loop is intended to do.  Are you meaning to keep recreating `input9t` recursively like you are?  If you've finished reading in all the lines from the scanner, why do you want to call it again later?

Comment: Do you intend to have two scanners `input9` and `input9t`, or is this a typo?

Comment: See my edit for explanation.

Comment: The only difference between a `do-while` loop and a `while` loop is that a `while` loop might not execute the body at all, while a `do-while` loop always executes it at least once.  Other than that, they perform the same operations, so changing the type of loop would not solve anything.

Comment: ya but isnt he saying that sometimes the body is not executing? a do while loop as you said will guarantee that it does at least once...I am probably misreading the question

Comment: The question is: after the second system there is no empty line. How to break out of the while loop after the last line has been read in?

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem is.  Anyway, if you change it to a `do-while`, it looks like the only possible effect is to call `nextLine` (the first time) when `hasNextLine()` is `false`, which would throw an exception.  Doesn't look like a solution to me.

Comment: @user1189952 Why do you think you're not breaking out of the `while` loop?  My suspicion is that you've misidentified the problem.  Does the `scanstringadd` string that you print out look wrong?  Is it possible that the problem is that you're not breaking out of the `for` loop soon enough?

Comment: I tried an input file consisting out of 2 systems of 6 lines, which works. So the problem is that the program expects 2 more lines when the second system has 4 lines. I found that this is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The while loop will automatically exit when the last line is read because there won't be anymore lines to be read. `input9.hasNextLine()` will be `false`.

On a side note, get into the habit of using [StringBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) instead of concatenating strings like this: `scanstringadd += scanstring;`

This is not good for performance.

Comment: Maybe the code above works fine. But do you know why I am getting a NoSuchElementException later when I call input9t?

Comment: I'm not sure, but it could possibly because all the strings are concatenated into one long string. From the code there seems to be no "\n" each time you append a string to the previous one. So when you call `hasNextLine()` there's no element thus throwing the error.